# Torchvision 0.2.1 transforms.Normalize does not work as expected

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, normalize, torchvision

I am trying a new code using Pytorch. In this code, to load the dataset (CIFAR10), I am using torchvision's datasets. I define two transform functions ToTensor() and Normalize(). After normalize I expect the data in the dataset should be between 0 and 1. But the max value is still 255. I also inserted a print statement inside the '__call__' function of Normalize class in transforms.py (Lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\transforms.py). This print is not printed while running the code too. Not sure what is happening. Every page I visited in the internet, mentions the usage almost the same way as I do. For example some sites I visited
https://github.com/adventuresinML/adventures-in-ml-code/blob/master/pytorch_nn.py
https://github.com/pytorch/tutorials/blob/master/beginner_source/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.py

My code is given below. This reads the dataset with and without Normalize, then prints some stats. The min and max printed is an indicator of whether the data is normalized or not.

```
import torchvision as tv
import numpy as np

dataDir = 'D:\\general\\ML_DL\\datasets\\CIFAR'

trainTransform  = tv.transforms.Compose([tv.transforms.ToTensor()])
trainSet        = tv.datasets.CIFAR10(dataDir, train=True, download=False, transform=trainTransform)
print (trainSet.train_data.mean(axis=(0,1,2))/255)
print (trainSet.train_data.min())
print (trainSet.train_data.max())
print (trainSet.train_data.shape)

trainTransform  = tv.transforms.Compose([tv.transforms.ToTensor(), tv.transforms.Normalize((0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4466), (0.247, 0.243, 0.261))])
trainSet        = tv.datasets.CIFAR10(dataDir, train=True, download=False, transform=trainTransform)
print (trainSet.train_data.mean(axis=(0,1,2))/255)
print (trainSet.train_data.min())
print (trainSet.train_data.max())
print (trainSet.train_data.shape)
```

The output looks like,

```
[ 0.49139968  0.48215841  0.44653091]
0
255
(50000, 32, 32, 3)
[ 0.49139968  0.48215841  0.44653091]
0
255
(50000, 32, 32, 3)
```

Please help me understand this better. As most of the functions I tried, ends up with similar results - for example Grayscale, CenterCrop too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in the code you have laid out a plan that how you want to process your data. You have created a data pipeline through which your data will flow and multiple transforms will be applied.

However, You forgot to call `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`. Until this is called, transformations on your data won't be applied. You can read more about it [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader).

Now when we add the above to your code like the following -

```
trainTransform  = tv.transforms.Compose([tv.transforms.ToTensor(), 
                  tv.transforms.Normalize((0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4466), (0.247, 0.243, 0.261))])

trainSet = tv.datasets.CIFAR10(root=dataDir, train=True,
                                    download=False, transform=trainTransform)

dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=32, shuffle=False, num_workers=4)
```

and printed images like the following -

```
images, labels = iter(dataloader).next()
print images
print images.max()
print images.min()
```

We get `Tensors` having transformations we have applied.

A small snippet of the output

```
[[ 1.8649,  1.8198,  1.8348,  ...,  0.3924,  0.3774,  0.2572],
      [ 1.9701,  1.9550,  1.9851,  ...,  0.7230,  0.6929,  0.6629],
      [ 2.0001,  1.9550,  2.0001,  ...,  0.7831,  0.7530,  0.7079],
      ...,
      [-0.8096, -1.0049, -1.0350,  ..., -1.3355, -1.3655, -1.4256],
      [-0.7796, -0.8697, -0.9749,  ..., -1.2754, -1.4557, -1.5609],
      [-0.7645, -0.7946, -0.9298,  ..., -1.4106, -1.5308, -1.5909]]]])
tensor(2.1309)
tensor(-1.9895)
```

Secondly, `transforms.Normalize(mean,std)` applies `input[channel] = (input[channel] - mean[channel]) / std[channel]` so according to the mean and standard deviation we are providing we can't get values after transformation in the range of `(0,1)`. In case you want values between `(-1,1)` you can use the following -

```
trainTransform  = tv.transforms.Compose([tv.transforms.ToTensor(), 
                  tv.transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])
```

I hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thanks Vipul. It works correctly. Thanks for the detailed reply and pointing out about the normalization also.

Comment: More information on this Normalization is available at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score

Comment: Can someone clarify how come the mean and std of the data have to be provided instead of calculated? According to the documentation, that is the values that will be used in the formula to compute the output. So, if the mean of my data is 128, how come subtracting my samples by 0.5 will turn their mean to 0.5??? Something very confusing for me, still.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like while reading without Normalization and converting into tensors itself, they are automatically normalized in 0 to 1 range. When we apply Normalization, it applies the formula you mentioned on this data ranging 0 to 1. Below is the modified working code with some print statements showing when the '__call__' function inside Normalize class is called, as well as showing how the values are normalized.The first value is 0.2314. Normalizing with 0.5 makes it (0.2314-0.5)/0.5 = -0.5372. The first print and the second print of tensor value shows this.

Code

```
import torchvision as tv
import numpy as np
import torch.utils.data as data

dataDir         = 'D:\\general\\ML_DL\\datasets\\CIFAR'

trainTransform  = tv.transforms.Compose([tv.transforms.ToTensor()])

trainSet        = tv.datasets.CIFAR10(dataDir, train=True, download=False, transform=trainTransform)
print ('Approach1 Step1 done')
dataloader      = data.DataLoader(trainSet, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, num_workers=0)
print ('Approach1 Step2 done')
images, labels  = iter(dataloader).next()
print ('Approach1 Step3 done')
print (images[0,0])
print (images.max())
print (images.min())
print (images.mean())

#trainTransform = tv.transforms.Compose([tv.transforms.ToTensor(), tv.transforms.Normalize((0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4466), (0.247, 0.243, 0.261))])
trainTransform  = tv.transforms.Compose([tv.transforms.ToTensor(), tv.transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])
trainSet        = tv.datasets.CIFAR10(dataDir, train=True, download=False, transform=trainTransform)
print ('Approach2 Step1 done')
dataloader      = data.DataLoader(trainSet, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, num_workers=0)
print ('Approach2 Step2 done')
images, labels  = iter(dataloader).next()
print ('Approach2 Step3 done')
print (images[0,0])
print (images.max())
print (images.min())
print (images.mean())
```

And the output for the above code is

```
Approach1 Step1 done
Approach1 Step2 done
Approach1 Step3 done
tensor([[0.2314, 0.1686, 0.1961,  ..., 0.6196, 0.5961, 0.5804],
        [0.0627, 0.0000, 0.0706,  ..., 0.4824, 0.4667, 0.4784],
        [0.0980, 0.0627, 0.1922,  ..., 0.4627, 0.4706, 0.4275],
        ...,
        [0.8157, 0.7882, 0.7765,  ..., 0.6275, 0.2196, 0.2078],
        [0.7059, 0.6784, 0.7294,  ..., 0.7216, 0.3804, 0.3255],
        [0.6941, 0.6588, 0.7020,  ..., 0.8471, 0.5922, 0.4824]])
tensor(1.)
tensor(0.)
tensor(0.4057)
Approach2 Step1 done
Approach2 Step2 done
__call__ inside Normalization is called
Approach2 Step3 done
tensor([[-0.5373, -0.6627, -0.6078,  ...,  0.2392,  0.1922,  0.1608],
        [-0.8745, -1.0000, -0.8588,  ..., -0.0353, -0.0667, -0.0431],
        [-0.8039, -0.8745, -0.6157,  ..., -0.0745, -0.0588, -0.1451],
        ...,
        [ 0.6314,  0.5765,  0.5529,  ...,  0.2549, -0.5608, -0.5843],
        [ 0.4118,  0.3569,  0.4588,  ...,  0.4431, -0.2392, -0.3490],
        [ 0.3882,  0.3176,  0.4039,  ...,  0.6941,  0.1843, -0.0353]])
tensor(1.)
tensor(-1.)
tensor(-0.1886)
```

Comment: For @Thiagarajan's statement "Looks like while reading without Normalization and converting into tensors itself", it is true: check source code of the class ToTensor from https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py or its docstring: Converts a PIL Image or numpy.ndarray (H x W x C) in the range
    [0, 255] to a torch.FloatTensor of shape (C x H x W) in the range [0.0, 1.0]. So caling to [0, 1] is done by default by ToTensor transform.

Answer (score 0):

You are directly indexing the underlying non-transformed data using trainSet.train_data. Try to index the Dataset, to get the transformed tensors trainSet[index].

I tried to replicate the problem and here is the solution:
[image]